# I need my slider to stay fixed at top of page

Tags: html, css

I need my slider to stay fixed at the top of my page with my content (text) to be below it, but for some reason my text and content is scrolling behind the slider and the text/content is fading in and out below is the HTML code

```
<style type="text/css">.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;  
    z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: center top;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(/ckfinder/userfiles/7699/images/1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(/ckfinder/userfiles/7699/images/4.jpg);
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(/ckfinder/userfiles/7699/images/7.jpg);
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(/ckfinder/userfiles/7699/images/12.jpg);
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url(/ckfinder/userfiles/7699/images/14.jpg);
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(/ckfinder/userfiles/7699/images/26.jpg);
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div { 
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div { 
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
</head>
</style>
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 05</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 06</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your problem with that code. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I am looking for this effect from this website http://pinnaclehomebuildingsolutions.com/  where the top of the page is full width and has a slider can you help?

Comment: I agree, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful to see what's going wrong. Two potential problems in the code you've shown are that you close `</head>` before you close `</style>` and there doesn't seem to be any `<body>`.